# How to restrict sftp and pem file to connect from limited ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I am using AWS ec2 console. I have pem file by using this I can connect through FTP and terminal. But I want that this connection should work only from certain IP address. I have basic idea that It is doable through security groups. But I don't know the full steps

Answer (score 0):

Update your EC2 Security Group

At port 22 record, change from '0.0.0.0/0' to your IP address